# Restkit - Child mapping doesn't inherit its parent mapping?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, inheritance, mapping, restkit

I have a `Parent` model that inherits from `NSManagedObject`, and a `Child` model that inherits from `Parent`.

Here is the `Parent` mapping:

```
RKManagedObjectStore* store = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore;
RKManagedObjectMapping* mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectStore:store];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"id"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:mapping];
```

And the `Child` mapping:

```
RKManagedObjectStore* store = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore;
RKManagedObjectMapping* mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Child" inManagedObjectStore:store];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:mapping forKeyPath:@"child"];
```

Then, when I try to map the following JSON object to a `Child` instance:

```
{
  "child": {
    "id": 7
  }
}
```

In the RestKit trace, I see the following mappings for `Child`:

```
mappings => ()
```

Why doesn't the `Child` mapping inherit from the `Parent` mapping ? How to make the mapping inheritance work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it doesn't work because RestKit doesn't support it, and in my opinion shouldn't.

If you want the child mapping to have the parent mapping you can just add it to the child mapping too, which is a single additional line of code if you write them independently, or just a few extra characters if you use the `mapKeyPathsToAttributes:` method.

There is an important point to be made about your specific example. One is that you shouldn't use 'id' as your attribute name, as id is reserved in ObjC (I'm not positive it would actually cause problems, but it's confusing to see in code, at the very least).

Hence there is a somewhat standard convention in RestKit to map "id" properties, which is to prepend the name of the entity to the attribute, i.e. `Parent` would have a `parentID` property and `Child` would have a `childID` property. That alone illustrates why inheriting these kind of properties (especially primary keys!) wouldn't be a good idea in the general case.

Additionally, it's common to have some sort of SQL based backend for a RESTful server, which may or may not support the kind of entity inheritance that Core Data has, so that convolutes the way objects are mapped from the device to data on the server. Rails, for example, handles STI to an extent, but anything more complex than that requires gems or hacks.

**Edit:** (taken from github issue)
If anyone finds this looking for a way to inherit, there's a relatively simple way to create mappings based on other mappings:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping* parentMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Child" inManagedObjectStore:store];
parentMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"parentID";
[parentMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes: @"id", @"parentID", @"property_one", @"propertyOne", @"parent_only_property", @"parentOnlyProperty"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:mapping forKeyPath:@"parent"];

RKManagedObjectMapping* childMapping = [parentMapping copy];
childMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"childID";
[childMapping removeMapping:[childMapping mappingForAttribute:@"parentID"]];
[childMapping removeMapping:[childMapping mappingForAttribute:@"parentOnlyProperty"];
[childMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"id", @"childID", @"child_only_property", @"childOnlyProperty"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:childMapping forKeyPath:@"child"];
```

Comment: You clearly explained why it doesn't make sense to make a child inherit its parent mapping. Thanks ! ;)